# LuaSocket in Windows - How to install and use it in an Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, sockets, lua, luasocket

When I run my code in terminal,

```
local function main()
    local socket = require ("socket.http")
 end
main()
```

I get this error/message: module 'socket.http' not found:

```
 no field package.preload['socket.http']
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket/http.lua' 
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket/http/init.lua' 
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http.lua' 
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http/init.lua' 
 no file './socket/http.lua' 
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http.so' 
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so' 
 no file './socket/http.so' 
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket.so' 
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so' 
 no file './socket.so'
```

I'm working with lua in Windows and I have no idea of how to implement this.
I want to use LuaSocket to get an image from http repository and then get its base64 encoded, **without downloading the image**. This with an image in a filesystem, this solution works:

```
 dofile("C:\\Users\\se47596\\Desktop\\LUA\\prueba2\\src\\Base64.lua")
 imagen = "C:\\Users\\se47596\\Desktop\\LUA\\prueba2\\src\\pruebaAsyncOCR.png"
 local function main()
   imfh = io.open(imagen,'rb')
   imblob = imfh:read('*a')
   imfh:close()
   print("ImageData="..enc(imblob))
 end
 main()
```

What files should I import to my Eclipse project? I saw these operations but I don't know how to use them...

```
  --package.path = "./lua/modules/?.lua"
  --package.cpath = "./lua/modules/?.dll"
  --local socket = require ("socket")
```

how should I structure my project? At least I have this:

MyProjectFolder

```
 |__src
   |__Base64.lua
   |__main.lua
```

Could you help me please? I want to prove it out of the Lua interpreter. I saw also these solutions, but I couldn't make it work in my Eclipse project, maybe I need a previous step.
Do I need to create a library? How could I do this in that case?

http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/installation.html
http://luarocks.org/

Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

First error looks like you are running in Linux??

Have you successfully installed LuaSockets? Its written in C so you need a compiler to install it. That can be found in Microsoft developer tools. You can also use cygwin.

Alternatively if you have mingw installed you can first download:
https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/blob/master/build/build-win32.sh

Then you can run:

```
bash ./build-win32.sh lua luasocket
```

Comment: Good point, sorry I take the error from other place (problems with copy paste...). I understand that I have to compile LuaSockets, but actually I don't know what to do with those files compiled...How should I add them to my project? Thanks for yor help! :)

Comment: I've test your command and I couldn't make it work (in cygwin):
`
      $ bash ./build-win32.sh lua luasocket
      ./build-win32.sh: línea 36: error sintáctico cerca del   elemento inesperado `$'in\r''
     '/build-win32.sh: línea 36: `case $ARG in
`

Answer (score 0):

I can build them by the way blow :

(1) replace gcc/g++ in build-win32.sh like thie:

```
 GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
 GPP=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
 #gcc $BUILD_FLAGS
 $GCC $BUILD_FLAGS
```

(2) apt-cyg cmake unzip mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++

(3) bash ./build-win32.sh lua luasocket